# Open or closed status of addition of two subsets of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Question**

Let A and B be subsets of $R^n$.

Define
A + B = {a + b | a ∈ A, b ∈ B}.

Consider the following sets

W = {(x, y) ∈ $R^2$| x > 0, y > 0},

X = {(x, y) ∈ $R^2$
| x ∈ R, y = 0},

Y = {(x, y) ∈ $R^2$
| xy = 1},

Z = {(x, y) ∈ $R^2$
| |x| ≤ 1, |y| ≤ 1}.

Which of the following statements are true?

a. The set W + X is open.

b. The set X + Y is closed.

c. The set Y + Z is closed.

**My efforts:**

I am able to see that the set given in option 'a' is nothing but the upper half of the plane which is open hence option 'a' is true.

I can see that the set given in option 'b' is x-translations of the curve xy = 1, for this I am not able to produce rigorous arguments.

In option 'c'I am not able to see how to solve this option.

**My questions are as follows:**

Is there a theorem to decide weather the sum  of two subsets of a metric space is open or close given the status of the constituent sets ?

If yes kindly state the theorem or post a link to it or please mention the reference book in which the same is elaborated.

If not could you please give me some hints to solve options 'b' and 'c'.

Comment: The sum of two sets is not defined in general metric spaces. If you look at topological vector spaces, or [probably] more familiar but less general normed spaces, some properties that are relevant in general propositions are "open" and "compact". These would answer the cases a) and c). For b), find out what set $X+Y$ is. It's pretty easy to describe, and you can immediately see whether it's open, closed, both or neither from that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint on b):** $$X+Y\ni\left(-n,0\right)+\left(n,\frac{1}{n}\right)=\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)\rightarrow\left(0,0\right)\notin X+Y$$

Here $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**Hint on c):**

If $y_{n}+z_{n}\rightarrow u$ with $y_{n}\in Y$ and $z_{n}\in Z$
then the boundedness of $Z$ implies the existence of a converging
subsequence: $z_{n_{k}}\rightarrow z$. This with $z\in Z$ because
$Z$ is closed. Then sequence $y_{n_{k}}$ also converges and this
to some $y\in Y$ because $Y$ is closed. Then $u=y+z\in Y+Z$.